# What is the maximum number of regions produced, i.e. $f(n)$, by joining all vertexes with line segments of a convex polygon with $n$ sides?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> What is the maximum number of regions produced, i.e. $f(n)$, by joining all vertexes with line segments of a convex polygon with $n$ sides?

[image]

For example, for the hexagon on the left, number of regions is 24, but the one on right is 25, which **I think** is in fact $f(n)$ for the case $n=6$.

So is there any way to find the general equation for $f(n)$?

Thank you.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72184.html

Comment: Good video explanation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8P8uFahAgc&feature=share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be fairly obvious to you (as seen from your two diagrams) that the maximum number of interior regions are generated when no three or more diagonals have a common intersection point. The proof is fairly simple for this. Now, we will consider the number of regions that are created when no three or more diagonals have a common intersection point. We show this by recursively adding an extra node:

Let the maximum number of interior regions in a convex polygon having $n$ sides be $f(n)$. For the base case, consider $f(4) = 4$, which is trivial.

Let us add an extra vertex $P_{n+1}$ to an $n$-sided polygon, to make it an $n+1$ sided polygon. It will have $n-2$ new diagonals originating from it. Let the vertices in the original polygon that are closest to the new vertex be labeled $P_1$ and $P_n$. Then, the side $P_1P_n$ is also a new diagonal in the new polygon. We note that once any of the new diagonal originating from the vertex $P_{n+1}$ enters the smaller polygon, when it moves from its intersection of any diagonal of the new polygon (including $P_1P_n$) to any other diagonal or termination vertex, it divides the region into two parts, thus creating an extra region. What this translates to is that the number of extra regions created *inside* the old polygon, is equal to the number of times any newly created diagonal originating from $P_{n+1}$ intersects another diagonal (including $P_1P_n$). The number of different ways this can happen can be found by fixing the ending point of the diagonal originating from $P_{n+1}$, and the possible ending points of the other diagonal. All three points will be among the vertices of the original polygon, i.e., among $P_1 ... P_n$. Thus, we have to choose 3 integers out of $1 ... n$, which is $n\choose3$.

Also note that the newly formed $\triangle$$P_1P_nP_{n+1}$ will be divided into $n-1$ regions by the $n-2$ new diagonals originating from $P_{n+1}$. Thus, the total increase in regions is $n\choose3$$+ (n-1)$, giving the recurrence relation:

$f(n+1) = f(n) + {n\choose3} + (n-1)$

Solving this recurrence relation gives the following closed form expression:

$f(n) = \frac{1}{24}n(n-3)[n(n-3) + 14] + 1$

Another solution giving identical (but expressed differently) result can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonDiagonal.html).

Answer (score 6):

Let $v$ be the number of vertices, $e$ the number of edges and $f$ the number of faces (not counting the exterior of the given $n$-gon $P$) in the resulting configuration. Then by Euler's formula
$$v+f = e+1\ .$$
On the other hand the number of vertices is given by
$$v=n+{n\choose 4}\ ,$$
because any four vertices of $P$ determine a unique vertex in the interior of $P$. Finally the number of edges satisfies
$$2e=n(n-1)+4{n\choose 4}\ ,$$
because each vertex of $P$ has degree $n-1$ and each inner vertex has degree $4$.

Solving these three equations for $f$ we get
$$f={n(n-1)\over2}+2{n\choose 4}-n-{n\choose 4}+1={1\over24}(n^4-6n^3+23n^2-42n+24)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Probably

> [A006522](http://oeis.org/A006522)   4-dimensional analogue of centered polygonal numbers. Also number of 
>   regions created by sides and diagonals of n-gon. 
>   (Formerly M3413)   12
>
> 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 25, 50, 91, 154,  ...

See its references, notes and formula's, for example it is the sum of several binomials.

> FORMULA  a(n)=binomial(n, 4)+ binomial(n-1, 2)+ binomial(n,2)+binomial(n,3)+binomial(n,4), n>=-1.

Nice tool, The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences!

Answer (score -1):

The most convenient expression for f(n) is
f(n) = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/24 + (n-1)(n-2)/2 which, of course, is f(n) for any irregular polygon with n sides (or any regular 'odd-sided' polygon}. For regular 'even-sided' polygons it is necessary to reduce the value given by f(n)
by counting the number of 6,8,10,12 ... nodes produced by the intersecting diagonals. For each 6-node the number of regions is reduced by one, for each
8-node by 3, each 10 node by 6, each 12 -node by 10 and so on in a triangle number sequence. For example, in an 18-sided regular polygon there are 216 6-nodes, 54 8-nodes, 54 10 nodes and one central 18-node ('hides' 28 regions). The f(n) value of 3196 is thus reduced by 730 to give the 'observed'(!) value of 2466.

Comment: Please use mathjax to render the math, thank you.