# area formed by diagonals of a regular n-gon

Tags: combinatorics

A regular n-gon with all its diagonals creates many regions of varying areas.  They can be overlapping (there can be diagonals within this region) and are bounded by the sides of the n-gon and one diagonal or by the diagonals.  Is there an estimation for the sum of all these areas?  For the unit square, the areas equal six: 1 with 4 triangles, 2 with 2 triangles each, and 3 with 4 5-sided regions having area 3/4.
[What is the maximum number of regions produced, i.e. $f(n)$, by joining all vertexes with line segments of a convex polygon with $n$ sides?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241887/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-regions-produced-i-e-fn-by-joining-all-vert) Just look at this drawing to see that there are many different overlapping regions.  What are their areas?

Comment: A picture might help here -- I have no idea what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Take an n-gon and draw all the diagonals connecting the vertices.  You will find many regions (enclosed areas) created by a diagonal and the sides of the n-gon or by the diagonals themselves within the n-gon.  Just look at a square to see four small triangles 1/4 the area of the unit square, four triangles each 1/2 the area of the unit square, and 4 5-sided figures bounded by 3 sides of the square and 2 half-diagonals.  The simplest way to see a picture is take a few minutes to draw a pentagon and its 5 diagonals and add areas of all  regions, overlapping others or not.

Comment: See for yourself  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241887/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-regions-produced-i-e-fn-by-joining-all-vert  See the number of these regions and find the areas even if the regions overlap other regions.